# Contact Form 7 - Multi Files Upload Issues

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, multiple-file-upload

I am using this plugin for upload multi files: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multifile-upload-field-for-contact-form-7/

**I received  attachment on my email by .zip format with all files. But, I need all files as separate attachments, no need to .zip with all files.**

Anyone can help me about this?

After reviewing the plugin code, I found that following code is generating the zip file:

[image]

So, anyone can help me in solving my issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No** if you are using that plugin.

From the [FAQ section of that plugin's page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multifile-upload-field-for-contact-form-7/#faq-header):

> Q: How can I get seperate files instead of one zip file as attachment.
>
> A: You can not, I am sorry.